# IE8 quirks mode issue:

Tags: html, internet-explorer, drupal

The website is made on Drupal 7. In that I'm using the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

While loading the website in ie8, the mode of IE changed to quirks mode and the website gets collapsed. To solve this issue, i added a meta tag

```
<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
```

then some pages loaded correctly in the standard mode of ie8. But some pages are still collapsed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "In that I'm using the doctype" - what doctype?

Comment: How do you infer that “IE changed to quirks mode”? What “gets collapsed” and how?

Comment: IE changed to quirks mode is inferred from the developers tool. Collapse in the sense the overall site is floated to left and not look like as modern browsers(firefox,chrome).

Comment: The doctype is given in the question itself.<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">